# What logic would I need to make this a good test for this map problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mocha.js, jestjs

I have this problem:

```
var imagenes = [
  { altura: '34px', anchura: '39px' },
  { altura: '54px', anchura: '19px' },
  { altura: '83px', anchura: '75px' },
];

var alturas;
```

The instructions for the user is to utilize `map()` and create a new array utilizing the `altura` property of each object and assign this new array to `alturas`.

So let's say the user receives this problem and does nothing just leaves it as-is, like what you see above and clicks submit, I want the output of the test to say "expected false to be true".

What is the best approach in terms of the logic I need to make this a good test? This is what I have put together thus far.

```
describe("is", () => {
  it("an array", () => {
    expect(false).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The user will type JS code into a web form's textbox and submit it.

I would like the test to check for what the value of `alturas` is.

So anything outside the correct value of `alturas`, it should output "expected false to be true".

And I cannot use libraries such as SinonJS.

Comment: Please give us an example. An input, and an expected output

Comment: @AniketG, I edited the question with an example of a user not providing a solution, they just leave the problem blank and clicks submit and in quotes I have what the user should see when they do that as an output of the test.

Comment: Be more clear on your expected output. It's confusing and we can't help if we don't understand the question

Comment: Is the user going to provide code? As in, do they type JS code into a web form's textbox and submit it? Are you going to run the code server-side? Do you plan on just checking what the value of `alturas` is? Or is there going to be a check whether they actually used map?

Comment: @ChrisG, I will answer the questions inside the OP.